# Setup database for Unit tests with Spring, Hibernate and Spring Transaction Support

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I want to test integration of dao-layer with my service-layer in a unit-test. So I need to setup some data in my database (hsql). For this setup I need an own transaction at the begining of my testcase to ensure that all my setup is really commited to database before starting my testcase.

So here's what I want to achieve:

```
// NotTranactional
public void doTest {
  // transaction begins
  setup database
  // commit transaction

  service.doStuff() // doStuff is annotated @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
}
```

Here is my not working code:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
    p:url="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:posmail" p:username="sa"
    p:password="" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>        
            <value>de.diandan.asynch.modell.receipt.Position</value>
            <value>de.diandan.asynch.modell.receipt.Receipt</value>
        </list>
    </property>    

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management 
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->

            <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

My Testcase

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/asynchUnit.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ReceiptServiceTest implements ApplicationContextAware {
  @Autowired(required=true)
  private UserHome userHome;

  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Before
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public void init() throws Exception {
    User user = InitialCreator.createUser();
    userHome.persist(user);
  }

  @Test
  public void testDoSomething() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Leading to this exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
    at de.diandan.asynch.modell.GenericHome.getSession(GenericHome.java:40)
    at de.diandan.asynch.modell.GenericHome.persist(GenericHome.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at $Proxy28.persist(Unknown Source)
    at de.diandan.asynch.service.ReceiptServiceTest.init(ReceiptServiceTest.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I dont know whats the right way to get the transaction around setup database.

What I tried:

```
@Before
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void setup() {
  setup database
}
```

-> Spring seems not to start transaction in @Before-annotated methods. Beyond that, thats not what I really want, cause there are a lot merhods in my testclass which needs a slightly differnt setup, so I need several of that init-methods.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void setup() {
  setup database
}

public void doTest {
  init();

  service.doStuff() // doStuff is annotated @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
}
```

--> init seems not to get started in transaction

What I dont want to do:

```
public void doTest {
  // doing my own transaction-handling
  setup database
  // doing my own transaction-handling

  service.doStuff() // doStuff is annotated @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
}
```

--> start mixing springs transaction-handling and my own seems to get pain in the ass.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void doTest {
  setup database
  service.doStuff()
}
```

--> I want to test as real as possible situation, so my service should start with a clean session and no transaction opened

So whats the right way to setup database for my testcase?

Comment: Please also make sure that your database supports transactions. For instance, MySQL will not support transactions until InnoDB dialect is set for tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following annotations did the trick:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
```

Here is the resulting full configuration:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ConnextConfiguration(locations={"/asynchUnit.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ReceiptServiceTest implements ApplicationContextAware {
```

Comment: Con*n*extConfiguration should be Con*t*extConfiguration; I cannot edit that mini-typo myself :)

Answer (score 3):

For spring oriented tests you can use the spring runner for JUnit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

documented here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch10s03.html

And the part that may interest you is that you are able to annotate methods with annotations as follow:

```
@Rollback(false)
@Test
public void testProcessWithoutRollback() {
    // ...
}



@BeforeTransaction
public void beforeTransaction() {
    // logic to be executed before a transaction is started
}
```

and

```
@AfterTransaction
public void afterTransaction() {
    // logic to be executed after a transaction has ended
}
```

you can even use something like

```
@NotTransactional 
@Test
public void testProcessWithoutTransaction() {
    // ...
}
```

to indicate you don't wanna transaction applied to it. But be aware of [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) document with the following warning:

> As of Spring 3.0, @NotTransactional is deprecated in favor of moving
>   the non-transactional test method to a separate (non-transactional)
>   test class or to a @BeforeTransaction or @AfterTransaction method. As
>   an alternative to annotating an entire class with @Transactional,
>   consider annotating individual methods with @Transactional; doing so
>   allows a mix of transactional and non-transactional methods in the
>   same test class without the need for using @NotTransactional.

Comment: I'm already using RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), now I complete my question with exmaple-code and exception
The other annotations dont work for me, cause Transaction isn't even started, so BeforeTransaction and AfterTransaction aren't called

Comment: could you provide spring and hibernate configuration?

Comment: Added the interesting part of my spring config. But I think the reason is visible in stack-trace: There is no proxy around ReceiptServiceTest.init. Whats the reason for this?

Comment: As an aside: meanwhile [@NotTransactional has been deprecated](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations).